# how replace a character in a string in javascript

Tags: javascript

i have a string :

```
var s="here_we_go";
```

how can i replace all occurrence of '_' by '$' so the string will become:

```
s="here$we$go";
```

Comment: Seriously... http://www.google.com/search?q=how+replace+a+character+in+a+string+in+javascript

Answer (score 7):

[Use `.replace`....](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/Replace)

```
s.replace(/_/g, '$');
```

The `g` here ensures every (not just one) occurrences of `_` will be replaced by `$`.